# Revert original master state by local

Tags: git, branch

I moved some commits to another branch by

```
git checkout -b old-state 0d1d7fc32
```

Now I want to push my local master state to master but

```
Everything up-to-date
```

occurs. How can I revert original state?

Comment: Your command doesn't move commits to a branch, it just checks out and _creates_ another branch. Your master will be left untouched. What exactly do you want to happen?

Comment: @Shahbaz I want master to be reverted to my local master head.

Comment: But you haven't changed master!

Comment: @Shahbaz  I reverted it to commit 0d1d7fc32, didn't I?

Comment: No. You just created a branch, named old-state from that commit. Master is absolutely untouched.

Comment: @Shahbaz, So how can I update it?

Comment: You need to be a bit more clear. Update it to what? You have no new commits, and no changes to master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's sum things up:

- you have pushed your local state of `master` to `origin/master`
- you did something wrong with that
- you want to reset `master` to revision `0d1d7fc32`
- you also want `origin/master` to point to `0d1d7fc32`

This is how to achieve that:

1. reset your local master branch to `0d1d7fc32`:
   `git checkout master`
   `git reset --hard 0d1d7fc32`
2. Make `origin/master` and `master` equal:
   `git push -f origin master:master`

Done.

---

Do not confuse Git commands with those you might know from other VCS. I know that there are some VCS where `checkout` means

> bring the working copy to revision whatever

This is not the case with Git. Maybe you want to browse http://git-scm.com/ to get a first impression what it's all about and then [read a book](http://git-scm.com/book) or so.

---

**Original answer:**
`git checkout -b old-state 0d1d7fc32` creates a local branch called `old-state` whose last commit is that one with the SHA `d1d7fc32`.

I assume you want to have `origin/master` on the same state as your local `master` branch.

In that case, do a

```
git push -f origin master:master
```

to make them equal.

[`git checkout`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-checkout) doesn't move anything. It just creates a new branch called `old-state` that shares the same history like the current branch. If you pass a revision number, it shares the same history **until** (and including) the given revision.

Comment: It's still "Everything up-to-date" message.

Comment: It's because everything _is_ up-to-date. You don't need to do anything.